# Change keyboard shortcuts for Windows IME

Tags: discussion

IME uses keyboard shortcuts like Shift/Ctrl/Alt + Caps Lock to switch kana modes. Is there a way to change this for a keyboard that lacks the Caps Lock key?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but might still be useful -- Another default keyboard shortcut to toggle the IME mode (and the one I always use) is Alt+` (the backtick on the upper left of most US keyboards, the un-shifted ~ "tilde" key, to the left of the 1).

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that one. Like you say, it toggles rather than selects IME mode. How do you select katakana mode if you're in hiragana mode and vice versa?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but you might be asking about this: when in Japanese mode, type a string and hit F7 to convert to full-width katakana, F8 for half-width katakana, F9 for full-width 英数, F10 for half-width 英数, and F6 to convert back to full-width hiragana.  F5 brings up the IME pad.  **Note:** This is all on Windows 10.  I believe these keys have been the same since Win XP, but memory fades over time...

Comment: Those shortcuts are a bit different, as they only modify the text currently being entered. After pressing e.g. F7 to convert to katakana, and enter to "commit", the next thing you type will be hiragana again. Often that's what you want, but sometimes it's preferable to just stay in katakana mode, which is what the Caps Lock related shortcut lets you do (same as right clicking on the IME tray icon). Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I can't seem to find any way of locking in full-width 英数 or half-width カタカナ input, but with the IME active in Japanese mode, hit Alt+Caps to stick it in full-width カタカナ, and then hit Ctrl+Caps to go back to the default of full-width ひらがな.  Is that the behavior you were looking for?

Comment: probably this should be on [superuser.se]: [Changing "Input Mode" on Windows 7 Japanese IME via keyboard shortcut (hiragana, katakana, alphanumeric; half/full width)](https://superuser.com/q/750591/241386), [How to convert Japanese characters into roman characters when you accidentally type an English word with Japanese input turned on (on Windows)](https://superuser.com/q/829427/241386). But I'm wondering which keyboard lacks the capslock key?

Comment: @phuclv one where you map it to ESCAPE :)

Comment: @phuclv, many power users remap the useless Caps Lock key to Ctrl or Super. Most modern keyboards such as the Keyboardio Model 1 lack it entirely.

Comment: @ArnaudMeuret "most modern keyboards" seems like an over exaggeration. Just a tiny number of keyboards (typically mechanical) lack such keys

Comment: @phuclv Apparently we disagree on the definition of modern. You correlate it to mechanical keyboards because most recent mechanical keyboards have had thought put into their design, hence making them modern and Caps Lock-less at the same time.